# jQuery library does not load

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to jQuery, and have created a simple index.html with an even simpler script. However, the jQuery library does not seem to load as in my firebug console I get the following error:

```
TypeError: $ is not a function
$(document).ready(function() {
```

Below is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Online Calorie Tracker and Analyzer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
     <script src="http//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="initialize.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Calorie Tracker and Analyzer</h1>
          <div class="navbar">
              <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                  <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Track Food</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Analyze Food</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
      <div class="hero-unit">
    <h1>A healthy you begins with tracking and analysis</h1>
     <p>10 out of 10 doctors agree. Losing weight is healthy. With our online calorie tracker and analyzer, the power is in your hands!</p>
     <button class="btn btn-danger" id="btn1">Get Started</button>
 </div>
    </div>


  <body>
<html>
```

And here is the jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("hello");
});
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<script src="http//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
```

Should be:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
```

Also it's recommended to load JavaScripts before the end of the `<body>` tag, to improve page loading speed.

Also:
Your end `<body>` tag should be `</body>` (missing the forward slash).

Comment: Took me a minute to see the difference even after you point it out here. To clarify I'd say the original script src is missing the colon after http

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, it happens due to internet problems also. Sometimes due to timeout cdn is not able to load the library. Try downloading the library and use it in the project in this case : http://jquery.com/download/.